# Kotlin annoation multiple targets

Tags: kotlin, reflection, annotations, jvm

I have an annotation like:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD, AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class Foo(val bar: Int)
```

And using some reflection I read this annotation like:

```
for (prop in myClass.memberProperties) {
   val foo = prop.findAnnotation<Foo>() ?: continue
   // Do something with foo
}
```

This works fine when the class is defined like

```
class MyClass {
   @Foo(bar = 1)
   var myProp: Int = 0
}
// prop.findAnnotation<Foo>() => { bar: 1 }
```

but when the class is defined like a `data` class with the property in the constructor the annotation is targeted as `VALUE_PARAMETER` and I cannot get it on my `memberProperties`:

```
data class MyOtherClass (
   @Foo(bar = 1)
   val myProp: Int
)
// prop.findAnnotation<Foo>() => null
```

I can of course explicitly target it with `@property:Foo(bar = 1)` but I would like to use it without worrying about this, much like `@JsonProperty` from `jackson` does.
When searching for the annotations I can of course check for the `memberProperties` as well as parameters in constructors... But `KParameter` and `KProperty` only have `KAnnotated` as a common parent, making a bit hard to work with both interchangeably since I also need the type and name for the property, not only the annotation.
Is that a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no good solutions, since it is a corner case. If annotation can be targeted both to VALUE_PARAMETER and PROPERTY, in the primary constructor property it will be placed to the parameter. The class isn't necessary to be a data class.

Either you can split this annotation by two ones (for parameters and for properties), or you can use `@property:Foo` syntax.